# soatest with maven having configuration issue

Tags: maven, parasoft

I have created a new maven project and I have added soatest in it. Now when I am trying to execute the test, it seems it is deleting the workspace before executing the soatest as a result it is unable to fetch the excel datasource.

My project in jave perspective:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CURvx.png)

Command I am using to execute the test:

> mvn clean test -Dparasoft.soatest.home="C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Parasoft\SOAtest\9.10" -Dparasoft.localsettings="C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Parasoft\SOAtest\localsettings"

[my pom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EutGO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use clean option for maven?
By default

```
mvn clean
```

will attempts to clean the files and directories generated by Maven during its build inside the target directory. 
Parasoft SOAtest will not delete your workspace, but maven will do if you ask for it.